# Joining named queries in JPA

Tags: java, jpa, named-query

I want to know whether I can join 2 named queries in JPA. As an example I have two following named queries

1 - Get all the active users
2 - get all the users for a given company

Is it possible for me to join above two named queries and get 
get all the active users for a given company.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `NamedQuery` for this. Directly passing a query string to the method is your best bet.

You must understand that the method `createNamedQuery(String name)` takes name of a named query. Whereas, `createNamedQuery(String qlString)`takes a query string, so this fits your need.

Or

Create a separate `NamedQuery` for this very purpose.

Comment: Why would the poster want to use HQL ? He says JPA, not Hibernate.

Comment: @DataNucleus: Oh yeah. Thats a `default` in my default settings. Sorry, modified now.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible for me to join above two named queries and *get all the active users for a given company*.

No, that's not possible. Either write a smart named query that can take parameters to express all cases (if possible) or use several named queries.

And if you are using JPA 2.0, the Criteria API might be another (better) option to write dynamic queries.